Firebase Database retrieve single entry if timestamp updated
I have a database that looks like this:
path1 > uid0 > node  
      > uid1 > node
      > uid2 > node

The node contains a timestamp equal to ServerValue.TIMESTAMP.
If I perform the following query:
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("path1")
.orderByChild("timestamp").startAfter(pastCutOff).limitToLast(limit);

The I get all nodes with timestamp > pastCutOff
If I only want to retrieve a single node I do this:
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("path1")
.child(uid);

where uid is a known uid in the database. All good so far.
I want to only retrieve a single node only if the timestamp is updated to reduce bandwidth.
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("path1")
.child(uid).orderByChild("timestamp").startAfter(pastCutOff);

But this returns nothing.  I've tried every combo I can think of to only get the node I want.  If I do this:
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("path1")
.child(uid).orderByValue().startAfter(pastCutOff, "timestamp");

then the logic works, but it returns only the long value in timestamp, not the entire node.
Is there a combination that will only return the data I want without having to create a persistent valueEventListener?

You're effectively trying to filter on two values (the UID and the timestamp) and that's not possible in the Realtime Database API.
The common workaround for it is to combine the two values into a single property, and then order/filter on that. So give each node an additional property:
"uid_timestamp": "valueofuid_valueoftimestamp"

And then you can order and filter on that:
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("path1")
    .orderByChild("uid_timestamp").startAfter(uid+"_"+pastCutOff);


As discussed in the comments, since you're now putting the UID filter in the conditions you'll also want to have an end condition. Something like this should do the trick:
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("path1")
    .orderByChild("uid_timestamp")
    .startAfter(uid+"_"+pastCutOff)
    .endBefore(uid+"~");

This works because ~ is after _, so by the moment you encounter $uid~ you'll be past all values for $uid itself.

Also see:

Query based on multiple where clauses in Firebase


That's a simple and clever way to work around the issue @frank-van-puffelen.  I think I'd have to add a .limitToFirst(1) so as to not match other UID alphabetically later.

Actually, if it does match other UID then it defeats the purpose...

Yup, that non-duplicate UIDs is what I expected, which is why I didn't add a limit to the query. But adding one is indeed a good idea anyway. --- What should I do when someone answers my question?

If I have UID1 = "abcde" with pastCutOff = "12345", and that's not updated, but another UID, UID2 = "bcdef" with any concatenated pastCutOff the search query will return this as it will match the startAfter("abcde_12345") attribute or have I misunderstood?

Yeah, you might need to also add an endBefore condition, to ensure you don't get data from the next user. I'd typically use something abcde~ as the end condition, as ~ is after the _ that you use as the separator.

Thanks! I got to the same place in my head for the end condition. Thank you for updating the answer. Much appreciated
